# Unix: awk save values as variable

Tags: bash, variables, awk, save

I have a filename with several underscores:

```
nc_glals_3_4.mrc
```

and there I can read out the values 3 and 4 with awk:

```
$ echo "nc_glals_3_4.mrc" | awk -F'[_.]' '{print$3$4}' 
34
```

But if I like to store `3`4 as a variable and recall the variable, it does not work:

```
$ variable=$("nc_glals_3_4.mrc" | awk -F'[_.]' '{print $3$4}')
-bash: nc_glals_3_4.mrc: command not found

$ variable="$("nc_glals_3_4.mrc" | awk -F'[_.]' '{print $3$4}')"
-bash: nc_glals_3_4.mrc: command not found

$ variable
-bash: variable: command not found
```

What's wrong?

Comment: `variable=$(echo "nc_glals_3_4.mrc" | awk -F'[_.]' '{print $3$4}')`

Comment: You need `echo` inside of `$( . . . )` just like on the outside. Bash is attempting to run your string as a program

Answer (score 1):

Just as you used `echo` on the command line, you also need to use `echo` in the sub-process call, eg:

```
# wrong:

$ variable=$("nc_glals_3_4.mrc" | awk -F'[_.]' '{print $3$4}')

# right:

$ variable=$(echo "nc_glals_3_4.mrc" | awk -F'[_.]' '{print $3$4}')

# or using here string:

$ variable=$(awk -F'[_.]' '{print $3$4}' <<< "nc_glals_3_4.mrc")
```

Then use `echo` again to display the variable's value:

```
$ echo "${variable}"
34
```

Answer (score 1):

If the numbers you want to retain are always in the same position:

```
test@darkstar:~$ Filename="nc_glals_3_4.mrc"
test@darkstar:~$ awk -F'[_.]' '{print$3$4}' <<< $Filename
34
test@darkstar:~$ Numbers=$(awk -F'[_.]' '{print$3$4}' <<< $Filename)
test@darkstar:~$ echo $Numbers
34
test@darkstar:~$
```

But if the numbers are not always in the same position and you want to catch all numbers between underscores or between underscore and full stop no matter where they occour:

```
Numbers=$(awk -F'[_.]' '{for (i=0;i<=NF;i++) {if ($i~/^[0-9]+$/) {printf("%i", $i)}}}' <<< $Filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question:

```
variable=$(echo "nc_glals_3_4.mrc" | awk -F'[_.]' '{print $3$4}')
```

You need an echo in your command.... now '34' is stored into variable.